# Should backups be owned by root:backup?

Tags: debian, backup, file-permissions

I have a central `backup` server running Debian which holds backups of various other hosts in the network, stored in a structure like

```
/media/backup/imap
/media/backup/wiki
```

With `imap` and `wiki` being hosts on our network. Right now, all files beneath `/media/backup` are owned by `root:backup` with `0750` permissions.  What's annoying about this is that

1. Every member of the `backup` user group can read *all* backups, including those of sensitive data (say: mails).
2. Right now one of the administrator accounts (`jim@backup`) is used for restoring the backups. It's annoying that this functionality is bound to a particular user.

Does this setup make sense? If it doesn't, what's a better approach for organizing backups? One solution I've been considering is to have different system users per host, so there's e.g. `imap@backup` and `wiki@backup`. The files beneath `/media/backup/imap` would then be owned by `imap:imap` with `0700` permissions.

Comment: When you restore from these backups, how do you restore the owners/permissions?

Comment: @nickgrim: We just force the permissions using `chown -R` and `chmod -R` right now, i.e. whatever permission/ownership is backed up, it's not used.

Comment: Oof, that sounds like it has the potential to cause exciting issues further down the line. I'd **strongly** recommend a backup solution that preserves permissions too, e.g. the one in @maikel-van-leeuwen's answer.

Comment: @nickgrim: It's not as bad as it sounds: for instance, the `imap` host *only* contains the IMAP server. We only back the `/home/vmail` directory (beneath which the `Maildir`s of our users live), all all data in there is already owned by `vmail:vmail`. Of course we wouldn't just force the same permissions on all files on a complete system. ;-) However, what I was trying to get at is: what permissions should we use *on the backup server*.

Answer (score 1):

Then use rdiff-backup. This keeps the permissions

http://www.nongnu.org/rdiff-backup/features.html

> Preserves all information: Whether you restore from the mirror directory or from an earlier incremental backup, rdiff-backup will reproduce your files exactly as they were. Files >missing at the time of backup will also be missing after the restore. Files hard linked when >backed up will be hard linked after the restore. rdiff-backup also preserves permissions, >user and group ownership, modification time, device files, fifos, and symlinks.

Comment: For restoring see http://www.nongnu.org/rdiff-backup/examples.html easy peasy.

Comment: Sorry, my question was imprecise: the backups of e.g. `imap` are already just backups of (in this case) the `Maildir` directories, which all belong to `vmail:vmail` on the `imap` host anyway. Keeping the permissions means that we copy the uid/gid which may or may not be the same when the system is restored. I'm rather interested in the permissions *on the backup server* itself, i.e. should all backups get owned by one user or not?